# Java application exits instantaneously

Tags: java

I am trying to make a java program that downloads a lot of images off a website. However, once I run the class, it instantaneously exits, and I can't figure out why. Here is my code:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Main {

    static HashMap<Integer, String> hmap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        for(int i = 1; i > 151; i++) {
            for(int i1 = 1; i1 > 151; i1++) {
                if(i == i1) {
                    continue;
                }
                String imageUrl1 = "http://images.alexonsager.net/pokemon/fused/" + i + "/" + i + "." + i1 + ".png";
                String destinationFile1 = hmap.get(i) + " and " + hmap.get(i1);
                saveImage(imageUrl1, destinationFile1);
                System.out.println("Downloaded " + destinationFile1);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void saveImage(String imageUrl, String destinationFile) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
        InputStream is = url.openStream();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile);

        byte[] b = new byte[2048];
        int length;

        while ((length = is.read(b)) != -1) {
            os.write(b, 0, length);
        }

        is.close();
        os.close();
    }

    public static void createHash() {
        //hmap.put(int, string) times 151
    }
}
```

What I want it to do is download, say, i=1 and i1=2, then download i=1 and i1=3, and so on until both hit 151 (they can't both be equal). In all, this will download 22650 files that will approximately be 27.6MB alltogether. So, that being said, is it a memory issue with the java settings themselves (I have 32GB of RAM, so me running out is not really an option), or is it a problem with the code?

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help me with this.

Thanks!

Comment: `(int i = 1; i > 151; i++)`??? [Look here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)...

Comment: OH. I always get confused with that. I always think it is when the for loop will end, and not when it should keep going... Thanks for that.

Answer (score 2):

i is never greater than 151 so you never enter your loops.

---

### Solution

```
for (int i = 1 ; i < 151 ; i++)
```